# Executar mais de um projeto no Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Em uma mesma solução do Visual Studio criei dois projetos, o primeiro para executar um Socket Servidor e o segundo como um Socket Cliente que vai enviar um arquivo, porem estou com dificuldades para executar os dois projetos ao mesmo tempo, alguma solução?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3850044/6809703

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nas propriedades da solução (clique com botão direito), você poderá configurá-la como **"Multiple startup projects**" e escolha no combo "**Action**" a opção desejada.

Veja na imagem abaixo:

[image: propriedades da solução]

Answer (score 2):

Uma forma manual seria executar um projeto, em seguida ir em Solution Explorer e clicar com o botão direito no outro projeto, escolher as opções Debug > Start new instance